# How to move recent data with column name or given value does not match table definition?

Tags: mysql

How to move recent data with column name or given value doesn't match definition table. For example, I have a SalesInvoice table and want to move it to the PurchaseInvoice table, from which the table actually has the same column name but a different structure (eg SalesInvoiceID in SalesInvoice is in column 2 and SalesInvoiceID PurchaseInvoice is in column 6)
I've tried it up to here but there is still an error

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO PurchaseInvoice
SELECT \* FROM SalesInvoice
WHERE SalesInvoice.SalesInvoiceID = '016'
```

Comment: You can not directly select as * and insert in to other table if both tables structure or column order are not same; You have to select and map data to respective column.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by mentioning your columns in order :

```
INSERT INTO pbx_intovoice.tag (column1, column2, column3, column4)
select column1, column2, column3, column4
FROM SalesInvoice 
WHERE SalesInvoice.SalesInvoiceID = '016'
```

If columns names are not the same as the receiver table you can still insert data from it :

```
INSERT INTO pbx_intovoice.tag (column1, column2, column3, column4)
select s.col1 as column1, s.col2 as column2, s.col3 as column3, s.col4 as column4
FROM SalesInvoice s
WHERE s.SalesInvoiceID = '016'
```